# Django helper application's static files not found in admin pages?

Tags: python, django, image, image-processing, nginx

I installed [Django-Image-Corping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) on my localhost and it worked fine. However when I tried to deploy the changes to my server (django1.8/Nginx/Gunicorn), in my djangoadmin's user table page I receive this error:"

> GET https://example.com/static/image_cropping/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css
> xxx.com/:13
>
> GET https://example.com/static/image_cropping/css/image_cropping.css
> (index):23 example.com/:14
> GET
> https://example.com/static/image_cropping/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js
> (index):24
>
> 404 Not FOund

Bascically the server cannot locate the static files, however in my localhost they are linked the same way and worked. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: Have you run the collectstatic command?